# How to make good multilevel login on codeigniter with 3 users role

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm going to make login with 3 users role and restrict the access only to specific page but whenever I tried to type the address manually, I can access the page when it should be restricted for specific user

I'm trying to follow some codes on the internet but this code only works for login but cannot restrict direct access when specific user logged in

This is controller **Login.php**

```php
<?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('login_model');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    function auth()
    {
        $username = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('username', TRUE), ENT_QUOTES);
        $password = htmlspecialchars($this->input->post('password', TRUE), ENT_QUOTES);

        $cek_us_guru = $this->login_model->auth_guru($username, $password);

        if ($cek_us_guru->num_rows() > 0) { //jika login sebagai wali kelas
            $data = $cek_us_guru->row_array();
            $this->session->set_userdata('masuk', TRUE);
            if ($data['level'] == '1') { //id_role admin
                $this->session->set_userdata('id_role', '1');
                $this->session->set_userdata('ses_id', $data['email']);
                redirect('page');
            } else { //id_role dosen
                $this->session->set_userdata('id_role', '2');
                $this->session->set_userdata('ses_id', $data['email']);
                redirect('page');
            }
        } else { //jika login sebagai mahasiswa
            $cek_us_orang_tua = $this->login_model->auth_orangtua($username, $password);
            if ($cek_us_orang_tua->num_rows() > 0) {
                $data = $cek_us_orang_tua->row_array();
                $this->session->set_userdata('masuk', TRUE);
                $this->session->set_userdata('id_role', '3');
                $this->session->set_userdata('ses_id', $data['email']);
                redirect('page');
            } else {  // jika username dan password tidak ditemukan atau salah
                $url = base_url();
                echo $this->session->set_flashdata('msg', 'Username Atau Password Salah');
                redirect($url);
            }
        }
    }

    function logout()
    {
        $this->session->sess_destroy();
        $url = base_url('');
        redirect($url);
    }
}
```

This is controller **Page.php**

```php
<?php
class Page extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        //validasi jika user belum login
        if ($this->session->userdata('masuk') != TRUE) {
            $url = base_url();
            redirect($url);
        }
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['_view'] = 'dashboard';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
    }

    function data_guru_absensi_add()
    {

        if ($this->session->userdata('id_role') == '1' || $this->session->userdata('id_role') == '2') {
            $data['_view'] = 'absensi/add';
            $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
        } else {
            echo "Anda tidak berhak mengakses halaman ini";
        }
    }
function data_orang_tua_edit()
    {

        if ($this->session->userdata('id_role') == '1' || $this->session->userdata('id_role') == '3') {
            $data['_view'] = 'orang_tua/edit';
            $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
        } else {
            echo "Anda tidak berhak mengakses halaman ini";
        }
    }
    function data_orang_tua_index()
    {

        if ($this->session->userdata('id_role') == '1' || $this->session->userdata('id_role') == '3') {
            $data['_view'] = 'orang_tua/index';
            $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
        } else {
            echo "Anda tidak berhak mengakses halaman ini";
        }
    }
```

This is models **Login_model.php**

```php
<?php
class Login_model extends CI_Model
{
    //cek email dan password guru
    function auth_guru($username, $password)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM guru WHERE email_gr='$username' AND pass=MD5('$password') LIMIT 1");
        return $query;
    }

    //cek email dan password orang tua
    function auth_orangtua($username, $password)
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM orang_tua WHERE email_ot='$username' AND pass=MD5('$password') LIMIT 1");
        return $query;
    }
}
```

I wanted to have right access for each user so they won't have access to another page if they are not the right user

Comment: As a side note, MD5 is pretty weak for password storage, you should consider using something more secure, like using PHP built-in [password-hash](https://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) library.

Comment: I think so but again, I was just following the tutorial through the internet. Can you give me the example or how to change it so I can use php's password hash?

Comment: There are example section on the documentation page that you could follow, basically it's using `password_hash()` to store ([example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php#refsect1-function.password-hash-examples)) and `password_verify()` to verify ([example](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php#refsect1-function.password-verify-examples))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are redirecting to the `page` controller index method, you could set the access role on the `index` method :

```
function index()
{
    if (!empty($this->session->userdata('id_role'))) {
        $data['_view'] = 'dashboard';
        $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
    } else {
        redirect(base_url());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in your page.php index() function instead of function __construct()

```
function index()
    {            
       if($this->session->userdata('id_role') ==1){ 
         $data['_view'] = 'dashboard';
         $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
       }else{
         redirect("login");
       }
    }
```